# How to get the averages of a 2d list and create another 2d list out of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a 2d list and I want to essentially split that list up into 2x2 components and get the averages of those, and then have those 'overwrite' my previous list. Assume that my inputs will always be a square (so # rows = # columns)
Here's an example:

input:

`[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]`

now imagine that I've split them up into their 2x2 sublists, which would look like this:

`[[1,2,4,5],[3,6],[7,8],[9]]`

what I want to do from here now is the average of each sublist and write it as such (so this should be my output):

`[[3, 4], 
 [7, 9]]`

(if my average is a float, then i simply round down).

The main issue I'm having is that my output is this:

`[[3],[4],[7],[9]]`

Essentially, it's almost like I'm `.removing`-ing each 2x2 square (or in some cases it's less than 2x2 as you can see from my example) and replacing it with the average for that 2x2.

Here's my code:

```
divided_matrix = get_2x2(original_matrix) #assume that this is the the list with the "2x2" sublists

    new_list = []
    for r in range(len(divided_matrix)):
        addded = 0
        for c in range(len(divided_matrix[r])):
            summation += divided_matrix[r][c]
        new_list.append([added//len(divided_matrix[r])])
    return new_list
```

I tried using `.pop` somewhere but that gave me an index out of bounds error because whenever I pop something the list size becomes shorter so I can't use len() and range()

Comment: "now imagine that I've split them up into their 2x2 sublists" you lost me here. Why did your 2x2 sublist lose their length of 4, and then on the average of them, you used numbers that don't reflect their averages?

Comment: @FelipeFaria they lost their length of 4 because after creating the first 2x2 sublist, which is `[1,2,4,5]`, the second one would be `[3, *whatever is beside 3*, 6, *whatever is beside 6*]` but since nothing is beside 3 and nothing is beside 6, the sublist just contains `[3,6]`. The same applies for `[7,8]` except this time it's because there is nothing below 7 and nothing below 8. The same also goes for `[9]` because there is nothing below or beside it. As for the averages, I think they're correct

Comment: Okay, I see. Then you have two options: (1) If you are making an algorithm that will generalize beyond a 2x2, you will have to fix the `get_2x2()` function because you are actually losing information on its output. Since you are doing `[ [FIRST], [SECOND], ... ]` and not `[ [ [FIRST], [SECOND] ], [ [THIRD], [FOURTH] ] ]` you are losing the position of the averages. If not, you can use that fact (it is always 2x2) to simply get the average twice and put it into a new list every time.

Comment: @FelipeFaria The name of the function is awful lol because it does in fact work and return things other than 2x2 matrices (it's only named that because the largest it will make one of the sublists is 2x2. If you have an odd sized matrix then that's the only time you'll get a non-2x2). As for the second half of the comment, I'm not sure I understand entirely, but this is what I've done: ```for row in range(len(lst)): 
        if row % 2 != 0:
            lst[row - 1].extend(lst[row])``` But now I have sublists that I don't want because they have repeated elements

Comment: @FelipeFaria for example, my function will return `[[3, 4], [4], [7, 9], [9]]` if we use the input was the same as the example in my original question. It should be returning `[[3, 4], [7, 9]]` I just can't seem to find a way to remove those elements now.

Comment: @FelipeFaria holy crap the rubber ducky method really works. While explaining my problem to you I got the solution. I'm just going to append every even indexed sublist into a new list and return that instead

Comment: My point is that the array `[[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 6], [7, 8], [9]]` has lost information from the original array. A return that wouldn't lose information would be `[ [[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 6]], [[7, 8], [9]] ]` (notice the position of the extra `[` and `]`), since now you are keeping track of the positions of where they need to be in the matrix you are trying to generate.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked out for ya. :)

Comment: Added an answer that might show ya that perhaps you are making the problem a bit more complex than it needs to be ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something along these lines -- assuming that you know the size of the original array:

```py
divided_matrix = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
size = 2  # 2x2

l, fin = [], []
for arr in divided_matrix:
    l.append(int(sum(arr) / len(arr)))

    if len(l) == size:
        fin.append(l)
        l = []

print(fin)
```

Outputs:

```
[[3, 4], [7, 9]]
```

Comment: @FilipeFaria although that does seem to work with lists that have an original size of <= 4, when i tried with an 8x8, I didn't get the right output

Comment: Weird. Welp, I'm unsure how to help. I don't know what `get_2x2` returns on all occasions, so it's hard to debug on my end. Whatever the case, I'm glad you found your answer. :)

Comment: Nevermind, I think all i needed to do was change `size` to equal length of the original list divided by 2

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear! :)